# Synchronization Service Manager Client - not quite understand "Metaverse Search" behaviour

Tags: user-profile-service

I am using SP2013 and have setup sync service with AD. I tried to use Synchronization Service Manager Client (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe) to troubleshoot the synchorization.

At the Metaverse Search tab, I added search criteria "Attribute=distinguishedName contains domain.com". I have 20 users in the domain and I expected it will at least return 20 resutls. The search get 14 results returned including the security group entries but some "users" are lost. I don't see any different between this "searchable" users and "non-searchable" users. Can you please give me some hints?

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Directly Editing the design in MIISClient is not supported. If you need to create an import filter you should do that in the User Profile Service Application under Connection Filters.

Comment: No I did not configure anything in MIIClient. I just want to use the Metaverse Search feature. I think the search cannot search on object within a "Container". I have setup sync on a security group "Sharepoint Users" and seems the group become a container